# Consulta en controlador a partir de ID con jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

Estoy intentando extraer los datos de una tabla a partir de un ID y mostrarlos con un datatable.

Mediante jquery, tengo la siguiente función:

```
var info = function(tbody, table){
$(tbody).on("click","a[id=ButtonMas]", function(){
        if(table.row(this).child.isShown()){
            var data = table.row(this).data();
        }else{
            var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        }

        var pc = data["id"];
        route = "/historico/"+pc+"";

        $('#ModalInfoEquipos').modal('show');

        var dt_historico = $('#t_historico').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": route,
                "dataSrc": ""
                },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "created_at" },
                { "data": "estado" },
                { "data": "ubicacion" },
                { "data": "empleado" },
                { "data": "f_asignacion" },                    ],
            "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },
            "scrollX": true,
        });
});
}
```

En mi controlador, tengo definido el siguiente index:

```
public function index(Request $request, $id)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $historico = HistoricoEquipos::Consulta($id);
        return response()->json($historico);
    }
    return view('historico.index');
}
```

Pero me devuelve un `json` vacío e incorrecto.

En mi modelo, tengo definida mi función Consulta:

```
public static function Consulta($id){
    return DB::table('historico_equipos')
        ->select('historico_equipos.*')
        ->where('id_equipo', $id)
        ->get();
}
```

Recibo el siguiente `request` y necesito el primer valor (1) para poder usarlo en mi consulta y obtener los datos correctos:

[image: Request - Inspector de Chrome]

¿Dónde tengo el error?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué no utilizas Eloquent para hacer la consulta?

Comment: ¿Sabrías un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo? No veo muy bien la diferencia entre el uso de Eloquent o mi códig.

Comment: @Shaz con lo nuevo que he añadido, sabrías indicarme por favor, ¿cómo puedo proceder? No encuentro como hacerlo. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, espero tu comentario.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar lo que hay en la pestaña Response de la última imagen?

Comment: En la pestaña Response, no hay nada, muestra lo mismo que la pestaña Preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a replantear un poco tu código de Laravel, para aprovechar las funcionalidades del Framework.

Voy a asumir que en tu modelo HistoricoEquipos la tabla que está conectada es `historico_equipos`.

---

Lo primero es eliminar el método `Consulta()` del modelo, el cual no se necesita según las prácticas comunes de Laravel.

Así que la tabla en el modelo HistoricoEquipos debe estar definida así:

```
<?php

namespace app\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'historico_equipos';

    protected $fillable = [
        // ...
    ];

    // ...

}
```

Ahora, en el controlador vamos a aprovechar Eloquent para hacer la consulta:

```
public function index(Request $request, $id)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $historico = HistoricoEquipos::where('id_equipo', $id)
            ->get();

        return response()->json($historico);
    }
    return view('historico.index');
}
```

Puedes leer más sobre Eloquent en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent

---

Después de la discusión en el chat, encontramos que había un error en la definición de las rutas, y que el método index no debía estar incluido en `Route::resource()`

```
Route::resource('historico','HistoricoEquiposController', ['except' => ['index']]);
```

La ruta debía ser agregada por aparte:

```
Route::get('historico/{historico}', 'HistoricoEquiposController@index')->name('historico.index');
```

Comment: He probado con la solución que comentas pero sigue igual. Lo que detecto es que si devuelvo `$request` de la siguiente manera `return response()->json($request)` sigue sin devolverme nada. Lo mismo me ocurre con `$id`. Ahora bien, si cambio el index y sólo recibo un parámetro, es decir, `public function index(Request $request)` y modifico `$historico = HistoricoEquipos::all()` si que funciona bien y tengo respuesta. Pero claro, de toda la tabla al completo, a mi me interesa de sólo un `id_equipo`. Gracias.

Comment: Lo mismo, no me muestra nada. He modificado la función `index` tal que así: `public function index(Request $request, $id){  dd($id);}` Y en el Network, la request URL es _http://127.0.0.1:8000/historico/1?_=1497375565102_ . La verdad no sé dónde está el error.

Comment: Buenas, eso es lo que he probado y sigue sin devolver nada. Dentro de mi controlador, en la función index, sólo tengo la siguiente línea `dd($id)` y no devuelve nada.

Comment: Bueno, si algo tan básico no funciona, no sé que tengas mal que haga que pase eso. Quita temporalmente `$request` como parámetro de entrada. ¿cómo está definida la ruta?  en routes.php o web.php dependiendo la versión de Laravel.

Comment: ¿Estaré enviando mal la variable $id desde jquery? ¿Es correcto enviarlo en la `route`?

Comment: La ruta está definida así `Route::resource('historico','HistoricoEquiposController');` en web.php